# Proving a tautology without using truth tables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that the ((p -> q)->r)->(p->(q->r)) propositional formula is valid without using truth tables.
I have tried using the logical equivalence laws to solve the problem but I keep getting stuck. ((~p v q)->r)->(~p v (~q v r))
=((p A ~q) v r)->(~p v (~q v r))
=((p v r) A (~q v r))->(~p v ~q) v (r v r)

Comment: Hi and welcome to the math SE. You can make your question easier to read by writing the equations in MathJax, for which there is a handy [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How to prove something depends on what you are allowed to assume. "The logical equivalence laws" can mean different things to different people. Best you tell us exactly what axioms and what methods of proof are allowed to you.

Answer (score 3):

We can simplify this a little by considering whether or not $p\to q$ is true in $$((p\to q)\to r)\to (p\to (q\to r))$$

If the left hand side of the implication is false then the implication is true so we only need to consider what happens when the left hand side is true.

If $p\to q$ is true and the left hand side of the above implication is true then $r$ must be true. Then $q\to r$ is true and the right hand side of our implication must be true because $p$ always implies true.

If $p\to q$ is false then the left hand side of the implication is automatically true and we know that $p$ is true and $q$ is false. But since $q$ is false, $q\to r$ is true so the right hand side of the implication must be true.

Therefore, $$((p\to q)\to r)\to (p\to (q\to r))$$ is a tautology.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have shown your attempt, I will try to answer your question.

\begin{align*}
((p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow r)) &\equiv ((\neg p \lor q) \rightarrow r) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow (\neg q \lor r))\\
&\equiv(\neg (\neg p \lor q) \lor r) \rightarrow (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv ((\neg \neg p \land \neg q) \lor r) \rightarrow  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv ((p \land \neg q) \lor r)  \rightarrow  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv (r \lor (p \land \neg q))  \rightarrow  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv ((r \lor p) \land (r \lor \neg q))  \rightarrow  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv ((r \lor p) \land (\neg q \lor r))  \rightarrow  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv \neg ((r \lor p) \land (\neg q \lor r))  \lor  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv (\neg (r \lor p) \lor \neg (\neg q \lor r))  \lor  (\neg p \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv (\neg (r \lor p) \lor \neg p)  \lor  (\neg (\neg q \lor r) \lor (\neg q \lor r ))\\
&\equiv (\neg (r \lor p) \lor \neg p)  \lor \textbf{T}\\
&\equiv \textbf{T}\\
\end{align*}